# Build a simple browser with python

Tags: python, webview, gtk, debian

I want to build an ultra minimal browser which will just load one url,  and will always be in full screen or kiosk mode. I will be running this in a Raspberry Pi. I explored several options in stack overflow and Google. Below are the potential solutions I found, but just can't decide the best and easiest method out of it.

1. Python + Gtk
2. QT
3. NodeWebkit (I couldn't get it installed)

One advantage if we use python is that in raspberry pi, I have Raspbian running which comes with python.

I would really  appreciate an opinion from experienced developers.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot really evaluate whether this is the easiest option but this is how you would do it with python and gtk:

```
from gi.repository import Gtk
from gi.repository import WebKit2

class  BrowserView:
    def __init__(self):
        window = Gtk.Window()
        window.connect('delete-event',Gtk.main_quit)

        self.view = WebKit2.WebView()
        self.view.load_uri('http://example.net')

        window.add(self.view)
        window.fullscreen()
        window.show_all()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    BrowserView()
    Gtk.main()
```